# Determine whether two line segments intersect, given that one of them is axis-aligned

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I'd like to know if a line segment intersects another, where the 2nd line segment will only be horizontal or vertical.

There are [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149622/147263) about general line segments, but this constraint may be able to reduce the computation required.

Ideally with only real numbers being used, not vectors. The inputs should be 8 numbers, being the 'x' and 'y' positions of the ends of the 2 lines. 
This is not homework.

Comment: What is the computation you're asking about?

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: What exactly are your inputs? Two pairs of points? Intercepts and slopes?

Comment: 2 line segments, as four end points, as 8 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the oblique line segment goes from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$, you can write its equation using the [two point form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) as $y-y_1=\frac {y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$.  Now if your second line segment goes from $(x_3,y_3)$ to $(x_3,y_4)$ (note the equality of the two $x$ coordinates-this is a vertical segment), you can find the $y$ coordinate where the vertical line would hit the oblique line, then check if it is within both segments.  The intercept point is $(x_3,y_i)$ with $y_i=y_1+\frac {y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x_3-x_1)$.  Now check whether ($y_3 \le y_i \le y_4$ or $y_3 \ge y_i \ge y_4$) and ($y_1 \le y_i \le y_2$ or $y_1 \ge y_i \ge y_2$).  The case for the line segment being horizontal is similar.